# Totaling the number of duplicates

Tags: mysql, sum

I've got this to find all duplicates in my db:

```
SELECT phone, count(*) AS ct FROM table GROUP BY `phone` HAVING ct >1
```

This results in 12 rows but the sum of ct of those 12 rows equals 26:

```
phone      ct
3600000000  4
3602931205  2
3602933399  2
3602933736  2
3602936241  2
3602937911  2
3602939287  2
3602939353  2
3602939767  2
3603174530  2
3606612300  2
3608995913  2
```

How can I modify the query to tell me the total of ct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this::

```
Select SUM(temp_1.count_1) as totalCount
from
(
SELECT phone, count(1) AS count_1 FROM table GROUP BY `phone` HAVING count_1 >1) as temp_1
```

Comment: This will include records without duplicates which the OP does not want.